# OpenCV image shows weird glare after un-normalizing with * 255

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I ran a frame through neural style transfer with MobileSSD.
Here is a picture of the problem I am running into, the middle one is the one producing the weird glares:
[image]
You must normalize the data like this to perform forward propagation with MobileSSD:

```
               (h, w) = noise_picture.shape[:2]

                blob2 = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(noise_picture, 1.0, (w, h), (103.939, 116.779, 123.680), swapRB=False, crop=False)
                NTSnet.setInput(blob2)
                output = NTSnet.forward()
                output = output.reshape((3, output.shape[2], output.shape[3]))
                output[0] += 103.939
                output[1] += 116.779
                output[2] += 123.680
                output /= 255.0
                output = output.transpose(1,2,0)
```

The weird thing is that if I were to imshow this output thing, which is divided all by 255 (and thus between [0,1], it will show the right most picture in my 3 pictures. But if I add it to a pitch black image with:

```
black_background[startY:endY, startX:endX] = output
```

And if I imshow black_background, it wouldn't work even though the range of values should also be [0,1]. However, when I do

```
black_background[startY:endY, startX:endX] = output * 255
```

Which unnormalizes the data (correct me if I am wrong). It does work, but it shows the middle picture with the weird glare, any insights? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be RGB->BGR confusion? Have you tried swapping the R and B values you're adding to output[0] and output[2]?

Comment: @Calvin Hey Calvin! That is indeed something I didn't think of. I tried swapping the values I am adding, playing around with the swapRB option, and just completely swapping output[0] and output[2], none of them worked. Can you inform me briefly on CV2's BGR system? Is it standard to use BGR in cv2?

Comment: OpenCV by default stores images in Blue, Green, Red order. I *believe* (not positive) the mean scalar values you supply to blobFromImage are in RGB order. Also, I believe internally dnn works on RGB images, and that's why the swapRB parameter is there. I'm not sure what order the bytes are coming out of your net. Maybe try output = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)?

Comment: will do when I get to a computer, thank you

Comment: looks like a type issue, the kind of artifact you see is typical when goes out of bound such as when assigning 300 to uint8 whose max is 255. Additionally, opencv imshow needs the range to be in [0,1] if it's float32 and [0,255] if it's uint8. so if black_bround's image type is uint8, and you assign a floating value to it, that kind of problem might happen. One quick way to check if that is the case is by `black_background=black_background.astype(np.float32)`, and show the image without multiplication by 255.

Comment: Hey, thank you @ZawLin, that indeed works, however, now I can't save with output.write() because videowriter.write only takes in uint8, any ideas of how I can convert float32 to uint8 smoothly? It appears to be if I do * 255 directly the weird glares happen (maybe because floating point errors), and if I do .astype(np.uint8), it doesn't convert the actual pixel values.

Comment: hmm...well in theory it should not happen, if your data is indeed correctly normalized within [0,1]. I suspect some of your values are greater than 1 or less than zero. Can you check if that is the case? Then you need to fix it

Comment: @ZawLin Hi ZawLin, finally got it fixed. Yes, it was indeed not normalized, I normalized it and * 255 and yes I can finally write my uint8 picture to videoFile!