# How to write a float32 picture to video file in OpenCV2?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am experiencing a weird problem here. 
I get back an output image from my neural network, it has dtype **float32**. I add a background picture I took from the internet, convert it to float32 from uint8, and then added my output on top of the background picture. 
Now, I want to save it, but cv2.VideoWriter.write(blahblah) only takes in **uint8**. I thought that to convert float32 to uint8, one would just do *** 255**, but that is probably wrong because I experience some weird glares (my picture can be found here: [OpenCV image shows weird glare after un-normalizing with * 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187730/opencv-image-shows-weird-glare-after-un-normalizing-with-255)) when I do so, probably because of floating point classic errors or things of that nature. So, how do I safely convert float32 to uint8? Or, how do I write float32 to file?

To be honest, I am very confused about some of the things. I know uint8 is [0, 255] and float32 is [0, 1], and I know that cv2.videowriter.write takes in uint8, that's it. On the side note, a solution appears to be to change everything to .astype(uint8) from the beginning, but I my neural net spits out a float32 so I have to work with that.

Comment: uint8 is usually in the [0,255] range (even when someone only wants to represent binary images) however float32 images are not automatically normalized to [0,1] (one example is when computing gradients we want to allow negative numbers too). Have you checked your minimum and maximum values in the float32 image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float32 does not set is from 0 till 1 that is mostlikly done by your neuralnetwork (softmax or sigmoid as last activation function). To set something to a different range this can be used:

```
normalized_array = (array - np.min(array))/(np.max(array) - np.min(array)) # this set the range from 0 till 1
img_array = (normalized_array * 255).astype(np.uint8) # set is to a range from 0 till 255
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding for so long, this worked perfectly :) And thank you for the explanation about the cause, I wouldn't have thought that it was caused by the activation function